# jQuery `on` and related selectors [Body vs Exact Element Selection]

Tags: jquery

What is the significant difference between the following two?

```
$('body').on('click','#selector', function{...})
$('#selector').on('click', function{...})
```

I have noticed that the first one more of dynamic thing. If I have static selectors, which should I use? What is the performance? What is prefered?

> **And Is it that: Always use delegation?** What are the side effects?

Answer here explains the use of both: [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on). I wanted to see the **performance** and **best practices** to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one

```
$('body').on('click','#selector', function{...})
```

Attaches the event  to the `body` itself, which means that any elements that were added to the DOM **after** it has loaded will also inherit this event (providing they're `#selector` of course).

Whereas this one:

```
$('#selector').on('click', function{...})
```

Is still a delegated event, but won't be applied for elements dynamically added to the DOM.

It is better to delegate your events because of the improved performance (especially when you have plenty of elements subscribed to the same event).

**However**, in your scenario your event is only an ID so there's only going to be 1 match (if you have duplicate elements with the same ID, it'll still only match 1) so there's no real benefit in delegating the event (unless you're adding said element dynamically of course).

Answer (score 0):

> An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):

Here's an example:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is delegation.

Your first example hooks the click event to the `body` and checks anything that propagates from child elements, checking it for the selector `#selector`.  This is useful for picking up events on elements not currently in the DOM or that get dynamically created and destroyed.

Your second will hook to the `#selector` itself.  This will break if `#selector` is removed from the DOM, but it doesn't have to listen to every child element and check it to see if it triggers an event.